# how to pass the value optained from html block to the writeFile command

Tags: javascript, java, cypress

This is my first time working in javascript and cypress, so I am a bit unfamiliar with the syntax, I don't know how to extract the price and write it in a document or in the command log

`cy.get('.product-page-pricing > :nth-child(1) > .d-inline-flex > .pricing-block > .product-new-price').then(price).writeFile('C:\path\price_cheking_on_emag_tablet\cypress\e2e\price_history.txt',price)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get(
  '.product-page-pricing > :nth-child(1) > .d-inline-flex > .pricing-block > .product-new-price'
)
  .invoke('text')
  .then((price) => {
    cy.writeFile('cypress/e2e/price_history.txt', price)
  })
```

Comment: thanks, it works wonders, but you forgot a full stop before the invoke command.

Comment: That's true. Thanks for pointing it out. Updated the answer.